# Mysql querybuilder with multiple parameters values

Tags: sql, symfony, query-builder

I try to get multiple values from setParameters, but with the same 'key', litke this :

```
->where('d.type = :type')->setParameters(array('type'=> 7, 'type => '8'))
```

But i have only result from '8', and not 7 + 8.

Comment: Keys must be unique

Comment: so i can't get multiple values from type ? With an other method ?

Comment: Do want get as `Select * From YourTable as d where d.type IN (7,8)`?

Comment: That's not a Symfony question, its a SQL question. You must use IN clausule from MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my title, and that was indeed 'IN' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `where` condition as follows

```
->where('d.type IN (:types)')
->setParameter('types', array(7, 8))
```

or

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');

// other parts of your query using $qb variable

->where($qb->expr()->in('d.type', array(7, 8));
```

With first example, if `array(7, 8)` is a parameter variable (passed to function) and it's empty, no error will be raised.

In second, if `array(7, 8)` is a parameter variable (passed to function) and it's empty, an error will be raised (so you should check carefully before run the query.